# How to practise 'Prati Prasav Sadhana'?

Tags: meditation, sadhana

I read online that 'Prati Prasav Sadhana' is helpful to recall ones past lives. But I couldnot find anywhere how to do it. Can you please let me know how to practise it at home.

Comment: Patanjali's Yoga Sutras.